# For NOT, when to use ~ or NOT?

Tags: python

I'd like to check if a dataframe is empty or not. use ~df.empty return -2 while using Not df.empty return False.

why I cannot use ~?

```
df.empty
True

~df.empty
-2

not df.empty
False
```

Comment: `df.empty` returns a `bool` object. `~` is the *bitwise NOT* operator, so almost certainly not what you want. You want the *logical* not, `not`. This might be confusing because `pandas`/`numpy` overloads the bitwise logical operators to perform vectorized logical operations

Comment: Because it doesn't mean the same thing as `not`; otherwise there would be no need for it.

Answer (score 4):

In Python `~` is the **bitwise not** operator, it takes the bits and swaps 1s and 0s. For boolean values, true is `0b00000001` and false is `0b00000000` so ~true is `0b11111110` which, since `bool` a special case one byte `int`, evaluates as the signed integer value -2.

`not` on the other hand is the **logical not** operator, if a value is true/truthy it returns false, if a value is false/falsy it returns true, it doesn't care about the specific bits, only that (generally) at least one of the bits is 1.

| Operation | True `0b00000001` | False `0b00000000` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ~ | -2 `0b11111110` | -1 `0b11111111` |
| not | False `0b00000000` | True `0b00000001` |

Comment: Probably an import point to make explicit, `bool` objects are instances of `int` because `bool` is a subclass of `int`

Comment: And more importantly, (most) operators behave *based on how their type tells them to behave*, so the what the tilde operator does depends on the types involved